# PHP not submitting values to mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to submit a form with php to submit the data to a table that I have already created in the database. All of the mysql_connect information is correct. Is there something in my code that I am not doing correctly?

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && strlen($_POST['firstName'])>0 && strlen($_POST['lastName'])>0 && strlen($_POST['email'])>0)
{
    $first_name=$_POST['firstName']; 
    $last_name=$_POST['lastName']; 
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $make=$_POST['make'];
    $model=$_POST['model'];
    $year=$_POST['year']; 
    mysql_connect("******", "*****", "****") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("buddyTruk") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE drivers ADD PRIMARY KEY (email)");
    mysql_query("REPLACE INTO `drivers` VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$phone', '$city', '$make', '$model', '$year')"); 

 } 


 ?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="drivers-form" class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="index.php">
                <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" required/> 
                <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" required/>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Phone" required/>
                <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="City" required/>
                <input type="text" name="make" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Make" required/>
                <input type="text" name="model" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Model" required/> 
                <input type="text" name="year" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Year" required/> 
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Hi, my name is `Rob'); DROP TABLE drivers; --`

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong method on your form. Change the form method to `"post"`:

```
<form id="drivers-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="index.php">
```

If you want to use `"get"` as the form method, you would access the values with `$_GET`, however, `get` is not recommended.

Please stop using `mysql` as it is long deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. Most importantly, **use prepared statements.** Anyone could easily steal and erase all of your data with your current code.

Comment: But "GET" is not recommended for forms like that

Comment: @Max Would 'replace ' work for my initial entry into the table?

Comment: @RyanSalmons I have no idea what you're trying to do with mysql.... If you have another question, post it rather than asking in the comments.